# Nativescript angular TCP connection library?

Tags: sockets, tcp, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Greetings fellow citizens of StackOverFlow.

I'm trying to make an IRC Client in nativescript, and I am struggling to find a library to connect to a TCP server for nativescript.

I tried with [nativescript-simple-networking](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-simple-networking) and [nativescript-socket-tcp](https://github.com/andreaCremisini/nativescript-socket-tcp#nativescript-socket-tcp)

The first one failed to compile with angular.
The second one upon installation it says that It's only compatible with iOS.

Any recommendations of a Library or how can i connect to an IRC Server? 
Is it possible to Connect to an IRC server with Socket.io?

Comment: Did you try [nativescript-socketio](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-socketio) yet? Between, you can always search for all available plugins in market place - https://market.nativescript.org/

Comment: can nativescript-socketio connect to an IRC server???

Comment: @ramon thats what you need to research and try

Comment: @ramon have you found a solution?

Comment: @Silko no sir i switch the project to use socket.io and forget about the IRC server